# How to list units with specific properties?

Tags: systemctl, systemd-run

I use `systemd-run --user` a lot to run things. I want to be able to list only those transient units, but there seems to be no option to `systemctl --user list-units` to do it. I also cannot list the `Transient` propery in `systemctl --user list-units --output json`, so this is also not working for me.

How do I list only transient jobs (`Transient=yes`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can always loop over all units and run `systemctl --user show -p Transient --value` on each.

```
systemctl --user list-units --full --no-legend --no-pager --all |
  while IFS=' ' read -r u rest; do
    [ "$(systemctl --user show -p Transient --no-pager --value -- "$u")" = yes ] &&
      printf '%s\n' "$u"
  done
```

A `user-unit-prop-grep` script could be written as:

```
#! /bin/sh -
systemctl --user list-units --full --no-legend --no-pager --all |
  while IFS=' ' read -r u rest; do
    systemctl --user show --no-pager -- "$u" |
      grep -H --label="$u" "$@"
  done
```

And then to list units with `Transient=yes`:

```
user-unit-prop-grep -lx Transient=yes
```

Or print the value of the `Transient` property alongside each unit name:

```
user-unit-prop-grep -Po '^Transient=\K.*'
```

That's quite slow as it runs several commands per unit.